# Equivalent condition for continuity in topological space.

Tags: general-topology, continuity

In metric spaces, we have this condition that a map $f$ is continuous at a point $x$ iff for each seq. $(X_n)$ converging to $x$ the seq. $(f(X_n))$ converges to $f(X)$.
Is the same true in case of a topological space?
i.e. is it true, A map $f$ on a topological space is continuous at a point $x$ iff for each net $(X_n)$ converging to $x$ the net $(f(X_n))$ converges to $f(x)$?

Comment: It's not true for sequences. See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/53695/sequential-convergence-and-continuity) post.

Comment: See: [Elementary Topology][1], S 6.6, Proposition 10.


  [1]: http://books.google.com/books?id=q8TttGzVGxUC&pg=PA130&dq=continuous%20topology%20net&hl=en&sa=X&ei=oesLUan3HoKq0AWr1IGoCw&ved=0CDUQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=continuous%20topology%20net&f=false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is true. This is more or less the point of nets. It's also true if you replace nets with filters.