# If $X$ can be described by sequences, then it is metrizable

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, convergence-divergence, metric-spaces

Does anybody know about a result like "If $X$ can be described by sequences then it is metrizable"? By "described by sequences" I mean (I think I do, not sure yet) that the topology of $X$ is given by a *sequence convergence notion.*

See my last comment in the accepted answer to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2493715/topology-induced-by-a-convergence-notion) question. There, @JohnGriffin comments  about such a result. In his words,

> "*If $X$ can be described by sequences (in particular, it is metrizable), then [...]*"

But, if the sequence convergence notion does not have the limit uniqueness property, then $X$ cannot be metrizable, since metrizability implies Hausdorff.

So, what would be a more precise statement? Which hypothesis, others than limit uniqueness do we add to sequentially described to get metrizability? It would be very helpful to have a result in that direction.

Comment: The sentence you quoted isn't meant to say that every space that can be described by sequences is metrizable - only that metrizable spaces can be described by sequences. Hence the words "in particular" and not something like "equivalently". Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Now I see. Maybe you meant "in particular, IF it is metrizable". But you don't need to apologize!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The statement under any reasonable interpretation is not true. They are called [sequential spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_space) in the literature, and there exists Hausdorff sequential spaces that are not metrisable.

One would expect this is the case because first countable spaces are sequential, which have a much weak condition of having a countable neighborhood base (in fact, a space is sequential if and only if it is the quotient of a first countable space).

For an explicit counterexample, consider the real line with the [lower limit topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lower_limit_topology). This is first countable and Hausdorff (and even paracompact), but it is not metrisable being separable but not second countable.

See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2148916/149608) which discusses sequential spaces in some more detail (in particular talks about sequential continuity).

Answer (score 3):

There are plenty of metrisation theorems that give necessary and sufficient conditions for a space $X$ to be metrisable. But none that I know of use sequences. IMO, A first countable Hausdorff space is the best-behaved general topology approximation of the sequence properties we know of metric spaces:

- A set is is sequentially closed iff is is closed.
- A function defined on it is sequentially continuous iff it is continuous,
- Sequences have unique limits,
- Being sequentially compact is equivalent to being countably compact and limit point compact.
- This class of spaces is closed under countable products and subspaces.
- If $X$ is a topological group (so it already has a lot of structure) then $X$ is metrisable iff it is first countable Hausdorff.

But such spaces can be far from metrisable, e.g. the Sorgenfrey line ($\mathbb{R}$ in the lower limit topology in Munkres) and the Double Arrow ($[0,1] \times \{0,1\}$ in the order topology from the lexicographic order) are first countable Hausdorff spaces with lots of extra nice properties (like Lindelöfness/compactness resp. and complete normality etc.) that are not metrisable. But from the viewpoint of just sequential convergence, they are indistinguishable from metric ones, I believe. If you can find a *purely sequential* property $P$ that holds in metric spaces but not in first countable Hausdorff spaces, leave a comment. I'd be surprised.