# If $X$ has not a countable basis why sequence caracterization of limit doesn't hold?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ topological space and $f:X\to X$ a function. We say that $f(x)\to \ell$ when $x\to a$ if

(1) For all open $V\ni\ell$, there is an open $U\ni a$ s.t. $f(U)\subset V$.

If $X$ is second-countable (i.e. the topology has a countable basis), then (1) is equivalent to

(2) for all sequence $x_n\to a$, the sequence $f(x_n)\to \ell$.

**Questions**

Q1) Why this caracterization doesn't hold if $X$ is not second countable ? i.e. I guess that (1)$\implies $ (2) always hold, but the converse is not true.

Q2) If $f:X\to Y$, to have the equivalence (1)$\iff$(2) do we need $X$ second countable, $Y$ second countable or $X$ and $Y$ second countable ?

Comment: For Q1), take a look at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1419938/example-of-topological-spaces-where-sequential-continuity-does-not-imply-continu) or [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/53695/422019). For Q2), take a look at  [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_space).